# pointer to struct variable not saving to eeprom

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have some code to store configuration data to EEPROM. The data in the variable configuration can be printed to serial console but cannot be saved to EEPROM. I am using ESP32 (Arduino framework). The below code is the shortened version of the code found in this [link](https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2017/09/how-to-load-and-save-configurations-on-an-arduino/).

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define config_ver "VER01"

typedef struct {
  char version[10];
  int settings;
} configuration_type;

configuration_type configuration = {config_ver,50};

void saveconfig() {
  Serial.println("Saving configuration!!");
  for(int i=0; i < sizeof(configuration); i++) {
    char data = *((char*)&configuration + i);
    Serial.print(data);              //<----- Prints fine
    EEPROM.write(i,data);            //<----- Problem!!
  }
   Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  saveconfig();

  Serial.println("Fetching EEPROM..!");
  for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    Serial.print(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.println("\n");
}

void loop() {

}
```

**Output:**

```
Saving configuration!!
VER01␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀␀        <--- prints fine!!
Fetching EEPROM..!
000000000000000000000           <--- Not saving to eeprom
```

Comment: "prints fine" but you are printing binary data. How do you know it is "fine"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I didn't get you. I can print something to console cant save the same data to EEPROM.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESP32 does not have EEPROM. It's just an emulation in flash memory. You need to commit your changes to move them from RAM to flash.

Add `EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE)` with the appropriate size befor your writes to initialize EEPROM emulation.

Add `EEPROM.commit()`after your writes to commit your writes to flash.

Refer to the official example:
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/examples/eeprom_write/eeprom_write.ino

Please note that EEPROM is deprecated. Use Preferences library instead.

See https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/EEPROM

Comment: @Piglet I will use the Preferences library later. I still have the same issue with the above code after adding EEPROM.commit();

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS you have to initialize the EEPROM library with EEPROM.begin . please follow the official example.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence can sometimes be problematic. I haven't dug into the precedence here, but suggest the following to prevent any problems with that:

```
void saveconfig() {
  Serial.println("Saving configuration!!");
  unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)&configuration;
  for(int i=0; i < sizeof(configuration); i++, data++) {
    EEPROM.write(i,*data);
  }
}
```